# Renaming files to the prefix and the middle portion of the file name

Tags: files, filenames, rename, variable

I have a script which at one point does the following:

```
for src in $(find -H "$ROOT_DIR" -maxdepth 5 -name '*.test' -not -path '*.git*')
  do
    fixed_filename=$(echo "$(basename "${src%.*}")" | sed 's/-test//')
```

Basically, I have files called `thing-test.js.test`

When looping through I'd like to end up with the filename being `thing.js`

Eventually then I'll create the full path to the file using `path="$ROOT_DIR"/"$fixed_filename"`

The above *seems* to work, but it's definitely not correct - I'm an avid user of shellcheck and it tells me there's a useless echo (I agree) and to attempt `${variable//search/replace}` if possible.

Would appreciate some help on cleaning up the above.

Edit:

The basic gist of what I'm trying to do is:

I'm trying to recursively search through every file in a directory following a particular file name pattern e.g. `file-test.js.test` and inside of these files are placeholder variables e.g. `REPLACEME` I want to find all these files, and one-by-one replace `REPLACEME` with a user supplied string from a read call inside of the bash script, and while I'm there I'd like to change the filename to `file.js` e.g. remove `-test` and `.test`

Comment: You're doing this the wrong way. See [the answers here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) Also, you don't need `sed` and `basename` for this job, shell parameter expansion alone can do it.

Comment: @don_crissti It's too much information for a title IMO, I couldn't think of a good title. I'm trying to recursively search through every file in a directory following a particular file name pattern e.g. `file-test.js.test` and inside of these files are placeholder variables e.g. `REPLACEME` I want to find all these files, and one-by-one replace REPLACEME with a user supplied string from a `read` call inside of the bash script, and while I'm there I'd like to change the filename to `file.js` e.g. remove `-test` and `.test`

Comment: I have edited my post now. 

For now, all of these files will follow the same pattern (`filename-test.js.test`) but I'm probably going to be extending the script to support other dash separations e.g. `filename-X.js.test` since some of those will be present too in the future but for now I was just concentrating on the originals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rename e.g. `stuff-X.js.test` to `stuff.js` (without knowing the extension before `.test`) you would have to use several expressions to extract the needed parts e.g. split the path into head `h=${path%/*}` and tail `t=${path##*/}` then get string before the dash with `${t%%-*}` and for the string in the middle get the name without extension e.g. `noext=${t%.*}` then from that extract what now is the new extension with `ext=${noext##*.}` so something like:

```
find . -name '*-*.test' -exec sh -c 'h=${1%/*}; t=${1##*/}; noext=${t%.*};\
ext=${noext##*.}; fixed=${h}/${t%%-*}.${ext}; echo mv "$1" "$fixed"' sh {} \;
```

Comment: `${var//pattern/replacement}` is a `ksh`/`zsh`/`bash` feature, not `sh`.

Comment: `${1%%-*}` may be problematic if the directory names contain dashes.

Comment: They're using `bash` but you're calling `sh -c`. That should be `bash -c`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` command coupled with shell using `-exec` flag:

```
$ find -name "*.test" -exec sh -c 'echo "$(basename -s ".test" "$1")".js'  sh {} \;  
one.js
three.js
two.js
```

Note that `basename -s ".test" "$1"` removes  the suffix, so you don't need to call `sed` in the first place.

If eventually you need to do something else with that "fixed filename", replace that echo with variable assignment and keep working within same `sh` command. Something like this:

```
$ find -name "*.test" -exec sh -c 'fixed_name=$(basename -s ".test" "$1").js; my_other_command "$fixed_name"'  sh {} \;
```